# Getting international stock data using yahoo finance

Tags: finance, yahoo-finance, stock, stocks, google-finance

Stock data can be optained using YQL queries like this:

[select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22MSFT%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)

I have to present in a javascript meetup where I will show some stuff to the dynamically updating stocks data with the YQL stocks api.

Only issue is that meetups are in evening time and NASDAQ is closed during that time. 
So I am open to foreign stock tickers which would work in evening hours of 6PM to 9PM (california). But I couldn't get a YQL query query running for any foreign stock exchange.

Any start-off pointer would be really helpful. Does anyone has experience in calling YQL finance queries for foreign stocks?

Alternatively, are there other similar services (google's?) which I could use for foreign stock exchanges?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an exchange specific ending like 0941.HK for China Mobile at Hang Seng Index. See http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EHSI+Components for other components of that index.